# Poisson equation in universe with gravity and expansion

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

According to the book *Cosmology* by Daniel Baumann, the Poisson equation for a static universe (a universe without expansion) where gravitation is neglected is the following, denoting by $\phi$ the gravitational potential and by $\rho$ the density of the fluid that fills the universe:

$$\nabla^2\phi=4\pi G\rho$$

The book makes a brief commentary about how this causes an inconsistency with the equations that determine the evolution of the fluid, since there are no static self-gravitating fluids. So, the next step is to include the expansion of the universe, which implies using phsyical coordinates $\vec{r}=a\vec{x}$ instead of comoving coordinates $\vec{x}$, where $a$ is the scale factor that measures the expansion of the universe. According to the book, this yields:

$$\nabla^2\phi=4\pi G a^2\rho$$

This is what I am trying to prove. My reasoning is the following:

**How the nabla operator changes**

$$\vec{r}=a\vec{x}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ r_i=ax_i\Rightarrow\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_i}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{dx_i}{dr_i}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_i}=\dfrac{1}{a}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \vec{\nabla}_\vec{r}=\dfrac{1}{a}\vec{\nabla}_\vec{x}$$

where $\vec{\nabla}_\vec{r}$ and $\vec{\nabla}_\vec{x}$ are calculated at constant time $t$.

**How the gravitational potential changes**

This is probably wrong since this expression is for masses that are considered a point:

$$\phi_x=-\dfrac{GM}{x}=-\dfrac{GM}{r/a}=-a\dfrac{GM}{r}=a\phi_r$$

**How the density changes**

$$\rho_x=\dfrac{m}{x^3}=\dfrac{m}{(r/a)^3}=a^3\dfrac{m}{r^3}=\rho_r$$

**So the final result is...**

$$\nabla^2_x\phi_x=4\pi G\rho_x\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ (a^2\nabla^2_r)(a\phi_r)=4\pi G(a^3\rho_r)\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \nabla^2_r\phi_r=4\pi G\rho_r$$

This is obviously not the correct result, as the form of the equation does not change at all and the scale factor is not present. Can anyone help me identify the mistakes I'm making? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The gravitational potential is the solution to Poisson's equation, so it isn't consistent to already impose a point-particle solution. Similarly, the density depends on the energy distribution of the fluid, which may have an infinite spatial extend and so won't generally have the form of an inverse cube law. The factor of a² arises purely from the coordinate transformation between physical and comoving coordinates, which you can see from the transformation of your gradient operator.

Comment: @haelewiin But the density and the gravitational potential have to change with respect to when they were expressed in comoving coordinates, right? So, they are being named the same way but are actually different, and the only thing that changes explicitly is the gradient operator, which is where the $a^2$ factor comes from?

Comment: That's right, the actual functional form of the potential and density will be different. But this is a consequence of a coordinate transformation, so the functions still describe the same thing.

Comment: @haelewiin Understood! If you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it and award you the bounty. It's going to be lost anyway unless someone else replies, and your answer was perfect so I would like you to have it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformations of the gravitational potential and the energy density is not quite correct. For example, given that $\phi = \phi(t, {\bf r})$, in terms of the comoving coordinates ${\bf x} = {\bf r}/a(t)$ one has $\phi = \phi(t, {\bf r} = a(t){\bf x})$. This notation is a bit unfortunate, but basically puts in an equation the statement that the function values themselves don't change under a coordinate transformation, only the coordinate points where these values are attained. As a result, neither $\phi$ nor $\rho$ contribute to the transformation of the Poisson equation. Transforming the gradient then yields a factor of $a^2$, consistent with the claim in Baumann's *Cosmology*.